# Ruby Rails is it possible to check before displaying form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to check submission before showing this simple form:

```
<%= form_for @article, url: {action: "create"}, html: {class: "nifty_form"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, size: "60x12" %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

like if its already submitted first time show other html content instead ?

Comment: Check the database and see if it is already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the object. If you're using ActiveRecord/Mongoid:

```
<% if @article.new_record? %>
  ... display form ...
<% else %>
  ... do something different ...
<% end %>
```